# Should [python] [arrays] questions actually about [lists] be retagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/array.html) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) are two different things in Python.

Asking list-related questions with tags [python] and [arrays] can be considered misleading, as they have nothing to do with the built-in "arrays" in Python. On the other hand, a Python list is a form of a dynamic array, so things get complicated and confusing here. So one might argue that a list-related question is about *a type of arrays* in Python (but not about the `array` module).

And there is another, perhaps better-known, thing called "array" in the popular NumPy package.

Here are the numbers of questions tagged by:

- [python] [arrays]: 19394
- [python] [arrays] but not [numpy] or [numpy-ndarray]: 8511
- [python] [list]: 37912
- [python] [list] but not [numpy] or [numpy-ndarray]: 36902
- [python] [arrays] [list]: 1747
- [python] [arrays] [list] but not [numpy] or [numpy-ndarray]: 1363

When you look at [the questions tagged [python] [array], but not [numpy] or [numpy-ndarray]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+arrays+-numpy+-numpy-ndarray), apparently there are a lot of questions about *lists*, but fewer about the built-in *arrays*.

**Question**: Would it do any good to retag list-related problems tagged [python] [arrays] to [python] [list]? Or would that be a waste of time and energy of the community?

I won't be going through the whole list of thousands of questions, but would be happy to retag when one comes to my sight.

Comment: If you really want to go through all the 60 thousand questions and make sure that they are correctly tagged, please feel free to do so. Thank you for your interest in that. That said, I find it pointless additional work in general. Users in [python] already know the difference between [list] and [array] and are actively involved in retagging the questions correctly.

Comment: @BhargavRao, no, as I already said, "I won't be going through the whole list of thousands of questions but would be happy to retag when one comes to my sight." Good to know that it is already actively being handled.